# How can I get user permissions of Google Search Console using API?

Tags: google-api, google-search-console

Using [Sites: get](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/sites/get) I can only get the permission of the current user (e.g. permissionLevel is siteOwner).

But I'd like to get a list of all users who have at least some permission for a specific siteURL. Is there any way to get these using the API?

Answer (score 0):

That API only gives you information about the site itself it does not have any user management functionality.

There is no way to list all the users or get their permissions.